# Distribute iOS app with web3

Tags: dapps, smart-contract-wallets, ios

I want to make a iOS app that connects to a smart contract. Does Apple prohibits to release this kind of apps?
I've looked on the App Store, and I couldn't find any app that is native and say, let you mint NFTs. Not even OpenSea has a mint option. Is there something in the App Store agreement, and my app will get rejected?

Answer (score 0):

By experience, the only constraint is that any app giving access to a blockchain must not be made available in China: local law prohibit them and Apple will reject your submission if you forget to remove China from the list of country...